# Select item in select2 with python selenium pack

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, jquery-select2

I'm trying to select item from select2 element (currently use chromewebdriver).
I run next code:

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
```

It looks like it works, because when I type:

```
element.click()
```

it opens the element and items are fisically visible.
But when I am trying to select item using:

```
element.send_keys('some existing item')
```

it raises an exception:

```
WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

Can someone help me with this stuff?

Add_1. The whole code is next:

`from selenium import webdriver`
`driver=webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Ikoropeckyj\chromedriver.exe')`
`element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_autogen23"]')`
`element.click()` #The list of items become visible
`element.send_keys('cash')` #'cash' is in the list of available items

```
WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

Add_2. Html for select2 element:
`<div class="select2-container ng-pristine ng-valid with-search select2-container-active select2-dropdown-open" id="s2id_autogen23">    <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice select2-default" tabindex="-1">   <span>Enter user template name ...</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close" style="display:none;"></abbr>   <div><b></b></div></a>    </div>`

Comment: post html code....

Comment: Provide with HTML sample for the same along with **exact** Python code. Note that considering your current code you will not be able to execute `element.click()` as `element` is a **list**

Comment: you are using find_elements which returns list so element.click() should not work and send_keys will not work either.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using find_element() method. Just posted Python code.

Comment: Maybe someone has had the same problem? Help, please.